# Handling 404 errors on incoming Google Drive changes

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on an application which watches a user's account for changes using the [watch endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/watch). On each incoming change, our application then goes to retrieve the change using the [get endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/get) so that it can be properly handled.

However, there are certain cases where the request to retrieve the change returns a 404 error. We have been able to reliably reproduce this issue with image files, specifically png and jpeg, by dragging a file from the computer into the drive UI to upload it. Oddly, this issue does not occur for the majority of file types (as far as we've seen).

We tried using a retry with exponential back off, but it seems the changes are simply not there. This is an example response that I got through the tools in the API documentation for a retrieving a specific change that had this issue.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Change not found: 18061",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "change"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Change not found: 18061"
 }
}
```

One potential workaround we are looking at using would be to perform a query on all the user's files using the modifiedDate parameter to look for files from the last 10 seconds or so, but handling the change directly is a much nicer way to operate.

**Update**

We've been playing with this a bit more and have found some other cases where changes reliably return 404 errors:

- When a file of any type is moved to the trash (if you open it when it is within the trash, a valid change comes through)
- When a file of any type is removed from the trash

**Update 2**

After some serious digging, it appears that if we subtract 1 from the "changeId" number coming in from the watch notification, we are able to retrieve a valid notification from the API that has the exact change we expect. Hmmm...

**Update 3**

When a file that's in the trash is deleted, the "changeId" number that we receive has to be decremented by 2 in order to receive the proper event.

Comment: id enter this in the drive api issues list that google maintains

Comment: Yeah, that might be the way to go. I figured I'd follow their suggestions first though: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/support

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that the change you were notified of was merged with another similar change that occurred just after it, and was deleted. In general it's not a good idea to directly fetch the ID of the change in the notification, since network conditions and other problems may prevent your application from being notified of each individual change.

Instead, when you receive and push notification you should use it as a signal that you need to sync all changes that took place from the last time you did a sync. In this case, uses the Changes.list() endpoint and set startChangeId to the ID of the last change you had previously synced to.